# How to run a Bittorrent mirror for various torrents e.g. from XML feeds?

Tags: linux, rss, bittorrent, feed, mirroring

I have a virtual server which acts mainly as mail server. I wonder whether I could set up a mirror for certain files like Linux ISO images, conference talk recordings and other stuff.

How could I seed automatically all torrents from XML feeds plus torrents added by hand?

Further conditions:

- The data files should be accessable via HTTP/FTP, too
- total traffic and bandwidth uage need to be restricted, plus bonus points for restrictions per feed or file

I hope to get a suggestion for a system which imports the feeds automatically and works without much maintenance. Any existing free software for GNU/Linux or something easily to implement in short time is okay. Recommendations highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [rTorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) to do what you want.  It's included with most Linux distributions.

You can configure a directory you can just drop `.torrent` files in via SFTP or WebDAV.  You can use the [RSSDler](http://code.google.com/p/rssdler/) add-on to automatically download from torrent RSS feeds.  (I assume that's what you meant by XML.)

To be able to download data files (and optionally upload) via HTTP you'll have to use [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/), [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/), or other suitable web server software.

You can configure settings globally in a [configuration file](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/browser/trunk/rtorrent/doc/rtorrent.rc#latest) and per-torrent via the user interfaces.  It has a full-featured text-based interface which you can access via SSH.  There are also a number of web-based frontends as well as one for Mac.  Finally there is a [XMLRPC API](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/wiki/RTorrentXMLRPCGuide) so you can do all sorts of things programatically.

Comment: TorProject's Tails wiki provides a nice tutorial on how to set up rssdler and rtorrent to automatically download new torrents to seed them automatically.  Please consider mirroring their project :D  https://tails.boum.org/contribute/how/mirror/automatically_download_and_seed_Tails_over_BitTorrent/